# Do I need to use Enum after I have used Stream?

Tags: elixir

I have a lot of data and I'm using `Stream.map/2` to get the result. So after using this function I'm getting this result

```
  #Stream<[
  enum: #Function<51.58486609/2 in Stream.resource/3>,
  funs: [#Function<47.58486609/1 in Stream.map/2>]
  ]>
```

Now if I map through the result and just return the value so it will return every value twice.

If I'm using `Enum.map` instead of `Stream.map` I'm getting the result. Since I cannot use `Enum` function here what should I do?

The result will be a list of map

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple answer is Yes
as it states here:
https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/enumerables-and-streams.html#streams

> Instead of generating intermediate lists, streams build a series of
> computations that are invoked only when we pass the underlying stream
> to the Enum module. Streams are useful when working with large,
> possibly infinite, collections.

Comment: I'm confused how do I get the result after this?

Comment: I got it. I can just use Enum.filter. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're familiar with any of the Reactive Programming systems like RxJS, RxJava, or Apple's Combine framework, using Elixir's `Stream` functions is like using the operators on a Publisher.  You're declaratively defining a processing pipeline but that pipeline won't do anything until a subscriber asks it to start emitting values.

In Reactive programming a `Subscriber` asks a `Publisher` to start emitting values.  The details will be specific to each framework but often there is a `sink` function that lets you specify a closure to receive values, or some other mechanism for a `Subscriber` to... well... subscribe to the `Publisher`.

In Elixir, in my experience, you use one (or more) functions in `Enum` at the tail end of a pipeline to play the role of the "subscriber" in this scenario.  That pulls data through the stream.

If you are not familiar with Reactive Programming and the previous explanation sounds like gibberish.  Please don't worry about it too much.  (though Rx is fun stuff and worth playing with in my opinion)